# My 'myQueueItem' in my Azure function producing a zero value when it gets triggered

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-triggers

I'm passing messages to my Azure service bus queue like this, where the 'MessageId' value is a string of a number ex. '345'. I see it in the queue in my Azure portal dashboard and when I look at the message in Service Bus Explorer I see the message id as the eventId I'm passing it.

```
 Message message = new Message
 {
     MessageId = eventId.ToString(), // passing it a value of '123'
     ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = enqueuedTime
 };

 var sendCodeSequence = await queueClient.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, new DateTimeOffset(enqueuedTime));
```

But when my function gets triggered I'm getting an exception saying the `myQueueItem` from the function is either **`0` or `null`**, depending on which function I'm calling.

Here is the first couple of lines of code for one of the functions that are giving me this problem. The event is always null and throws an exception because `myQueueItem` is always **`null` or `0`**.

I had this working before, I thought, but now I think changes were made and throwing exceptions each time my functions get triggered!

Question - Is `myQueueItem` not the messageId I'm passing it when I create and put the message on the queue?

```
[FunctionName("CancelEvent")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("canceleventqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "events2017_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            log.Info($"Cancel event started id: {myQueueItem}");

            var eventId = Convert.ToInt32(myQueueItem);

            using (var dbContext = new EventContext(myDatabaseConnectionString))
            {
                var event = dbContext.Events.Where(i => i.EventId == eventId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (Event == null)
                    throw new Exception("no event with this id: " + myQueueItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

myQueueItem is the message itself. string myQueueItem isn't really useful not if you have used a brokered message or service bus message and added other information you want to use in the function. You should replace `string myQueueItem` with `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message myQueueItem`. Also review the implementation in this post for some other useful information on serializing/deserializing the message if neccessary: [Azure ServiceBus Message Serialization/Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710568/azure-servicebus-message-serialization-deserialization)

Comment: I only need to pass an id from the message to the function, how do you recommend I do this? Additionaly, what I don't understand is that I had this working before and passing an id as the 'myQueueItem', now it's not working!

Comment: Have you tried var sendCodeSequence = await queueClient.ScheduleMessageAsync(eventId.ToString(), new DateTimeOffset(enqueuedTime)); ?

Comment: no, the first parameter only takes a message object

Comment: Now I'm just wondering if it broke because I think I added a scheduled enqueue time to the message. maybe now that changed it's structure so I can read it as a string, where as before I just had the id as a string and it allowed me to read it as a string without casting it to a object or reading it in as a Message object first..

Comment: That probably explains it. If you want to continue to use your existing structure, then you should replace string myQueueItem with BrokeredMessage myQueueItem. Otherwise, if you just want to send a single string, you can either revert back your code or use QueueClient.SendAsync(). Please also review the serialization scenarios for ServiceBusTrigger here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/ServiceBus-Serialization-Scenarios

Comment: If I want to continue using my existing structure, shouldn't pass in a 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message' like in your original response. That's the same type of object I put on the queue! I'm a little confused now.

Comment: The best way is to try both and see which works. Sorry, I don't have an executable version of your code otherwise I would've been a little more precise. The ServiceBusTrigger documentation indicates compatibility with BrokeredMessage. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message is a newer construct and ServiceBusTrigger may not yet support it. If it will only work with a BrokeredMessage you will need to send a BrokeredMessage instead of a Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message.

Comment: Do you have any link to the most recent documentation for the functions? I can never find anything and when I do it's usually out of date or  not what I need.

Comment: Either way thanks for the help that helps me out a lot! thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus . I've also posted a few links in my previous messages. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Can you describe your final solution so I can update my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by passing in 'string messageId' as a parameter in the function. I guess Azure messages are used differently then BrokeredMessages.