# Azure Functions v2 BrokeredMessage as input from ServiceBus

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I was following an example that targeted v1 Functions and what I want from it I haven't been able to replicate in v2.

I want the BrokeredMessage in the signature of the Azure Function.

```
public static async Task WhatIsTheTime(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(queueName: QueueName, Connection = ConnectionStringKey)]
            BrokeredMessage message, 
            ILogger log)
{
     var myObj = message.GetBody<MyType>();
     // whatever
}
```

primarily because it includes lots of handy metadata and I cba to change the signature every time I decide I want something different. Also because as the above example shows, its pretty easy to get the body.

However it seems like whatever out-of-the-box setup I have is furious at this idea. What it wants me to do is:

```
    public static async Task WhatIsTheTime(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(queueName: QueueName, Connection = ConnectionStringKey)]
            MyType myObj, 
            ILogger log)
{
    // whatever
}
```

and do that first step for me.
If I do this, everything is happy and we can all go home. However I don't want this, I'd rather the full BrokeredMessage.

No matter how I tried packaging the content of the body it failed miserably prior to my code executing giving me a host of different errors (depending on how I packaged it) but tellingly; this one:

```
Exception while executing function: Exception binding parameter Expecting element 'BrokeredMessage'
```

Where its trying to deserialize the BODY of a BrokeredMessage into a BrokeredMessage!
What gives? I've read articles that state putting BrokeredMessage in the signature makes this stuff easy. Am I missing a configuration option or smth?

Comment: This thread helped me with my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710568/azure-servicebus-message-serialization-deserialization/50711229

Comment: This helped me with the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710568/azure-servicebus-message-serialization-deserialization/50711229

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Functions v2 doesn't use BrokeredMessage any more, it uses [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message) instead.

Comment: oh, so I can still put a BrokeredMessage on the queue but can only take a Message off the queue. Fair enough. Do you know the design reasoning for the change?

Comment: I believe it's because Message is .NET Standard whereas BrokeredMessage is only .NET Framework.

Comment: <3. Thanks, makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---usage) is the information from Azure Functions Service Bus Trigger documentation saying that the Service Bus message in Azure Functions V2 supports `Meessage` instead of `BrokeredMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the broken [wire compatibility issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/239).
If your original code is constructing `BrokeredMessage` using a constructor that takes an object rather than stream, this will cause the new .NET Standard client to fail. Unless an extension method is used to retrieve the body, which I presume Azure Functions doesn't do.

In case you have an option to update and re-deploy your senders/publishers, you *could* change how you construct your messages by sending a `MemoryStream` with bytes for the Function to be able to process it.

Comment: nah, its not a problem with the insides, its the outsides that was the issue.

Comment: Insides/outside? Not sure I follow.

Comment: message vs body. You're talking about the body. My issue was with the message container.

Comment: The entire thing has also changed. `BrokeredMessage` vs `Message` that are not 1 to 1 mapping.

Comment: My confusion stemmed from my ability to put a BrokeredMessage onto the queue but when I tried to get it out it tried to effectively do Message.GetBody<BrokeredMessage>() because of how the auto-magic bindings work.